# Freezing Panes in Reporting Services Excel Export

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting-services, business-intelligence

Does anyone know how to freeze panes in Reporting Services Excel Export?

Answer (score 1):

The SSRS export to Excel feature does not support pane freeze. If you want your Excel file to have a freezed pane, you have to do it manually (like you would do on a normal Excel file).